# NoMethodError: undefined method `errors' for []:Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rake-task, rakefile

I get NoMethodError when I run `test` for the code below

**csv_importer.rb**

```
require 'csv_importer/engine'

class WebImport
  def initialize(url)
    @url = url
  end

  def call
    url = 'http://example.com/people.csv'
    csv_string = open(url).read.force_encoding('UTF-8')

    string_to_users(csv_string)
  end

  def string_to_users(csv_string)
    counter = 0
    duplicate_counter = 0

    user = []
    CSV.parse(csv_string, headers: true, header_converters: :symbol) do |row|
      next unless row[:name].present? && row[:email_address].present?
      user = CsvImporter::User.create row.to_h
      if user.persisted?
        counter += 1
      else
        duplicate_counter += 1
      end
    end
    p "Email duplicate record: #{user.email_address} - #{user.errors.full_messages.join(',')}" if user.errors.any?

    p "Imported #{counter} users, #{duplicate_counter} duplicate rows ain't added in total"
  end
end
```

**csv_importer_test.rb**

```
require 'csv_importer/engine'
require 'test_helper'
require 'rake'

class CsvImporterTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  test 'truth' do
    assert_kind_of Module, CsvImporter
  end

  test 'should override_application and import data' do
    a = WebImport.new(url: 'http://example.com/people.csv')
    a.string_to_users('Olaoluwa Afolabi')# <-- I still get error even I put a comma separated list of attributes that is imported into the db here.
    assert_equal User.count, 7
  end
end
```

**csv format in the url in the code:**
This saves into DB once I run the Rake Task

```
Name,Email Address,Telephone Number,Website
Coy Kunde,stone@stone.com,0800 382630,mills.net
```

**What I have done to debug:**

I use `byebug` and I figured out the in `csv_importer_test.rb`, the line where I have `a.string_to_users('Olaoluwa Afolabi')` is throwing error. See byebug error below:

[image: byebug error]

So, I when I run `rails test`, I get the error below:

[image: test error]

So, how do I solve this error, I have no clue what am doing wrong??

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @sawa The question is clear from the post.

Comment: Its ridiculous how people just tend to mark down questions for no reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have any row in your `csv_string`, this line:

```
user = CsvImporter::User.create row.to_h
```

isn't executed, so `user` variable holds previous value, which is `[]`:

```
user = []
```

As we know, there's no method `errors` defined for `Array`, yet you try to call it in this line:

```
p "Email duplicate record: #{user.email_address} - #{user.errors.full_messages.join(',')}" if user.errors.any?
```

and that's why you get an error.

Comment: Thank you so much @MarekLipka